# Laravel View::make is not rendering

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making Laravel package which has dynamic layout.

```php
$this->layout = View::make($this->layout);

$this->layout->header = __($this->form_name);

$this->layout->slot = View::make('form-generator::form')
            ->with('fields', $this->fields)
            ->with('route_name', $this->routeName)
            ->with('update_route_obj', $this->updateRouteObj); // this is not rendering
```

Here is the dump that I get from `dd($this->layout)`

```php
Illuminate\View\View {#1392 ▼
  #factory: Illuminate\View\Factory {#1373 ▶}
  #engine: Livewire\CompilerEngineForIgnition {#1387 ▶}
  #view: "layouts_admin.app"
  #data: array:2 [▼
    "header" => "Create Category"
    "slot" => Illuminate\View\View {#1400 ▶}
  ]
  #path: "/resources/views/layouts_admin/app.blade.php"
}
```

Here is the result that I get from the `View::make()`

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the slot inside your layout blade view with this syntax:

```php
{!! $slot !!}
```

This way, the `slot` data will be rendered and the html will be interpreted. If you are just using `{{ $slot }}`, the html is diplayed as a text (it is escaped).

Use `{!! $slot !!}` with caution, since any javascript inside the `$slot` content will also be executed, exposing you to potential XSS attacks.

Be sure to either trust the source of the content (admins only for instance) or to sanitize it if it is posted by users.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But after I add `->render()` it still not working

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is exactly not working?

Comment: i have add `->render()` and `dd($this->layout->slot)` and `View` instance is changed to HTML. however when viewing the page, the html is still like the image in my question

Comment: How do you get to the point where you are "viewing the page"? Are you doing something like `return $this->layout`?

Comment: Can you show me what `$this->layout` is in the first place? When you use it as an argument in `View::make($this->layout)`. If it's a blade view, can you edit your question with its content please?

Comment: I updated my answer so it follows the latest information available in these comments. No need to add `->render()` anymore.